# Put the incomplete line at the top

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I made a [flexbox layout](http://codepen.io/bjb/pen/Kwjobr) of a bunch of *things*. The *things* are like text (inline, flowing, and wrapping) except they expand evenly to take up all the available space on the line. But then I have this:

[image: The things on the bottom are fatter]

I want it to look like this:

[image: The things on the top are fatter]

How can I do that? Adjusting `flex-grow` and `width` won't help since I don't know which boxes to apply it to. `flex-direction: row-reverse` will switch *things*, but not layout.

Comment: What are these boxes? Divs?

Comment: I suggest using the 'html' variable and 'inserting' the html content line by line, at the same location, until all lines done.  This should put the short line as the first one displayed.

Comment: @KashishArora *Things*. Any block-level element should be the same.

Comment: @user3629249 What? We're talking about CSS here…

Comment: Do you want the first row to get adjusted instead of the last row?

Comment: @Barun Yes. Instead of 3 on the bottom and 4 everywhere else, I want 3 on the top and 4 everywhere else.

Comment: Then you can use one flex container for first three and another flex container for the remaining.

Comment: @Barun When the window gets bigger or smaller, the *things* per row changes. So that would be difficult.

Comment: then give the parent block a fixed width like 1290px

Comment: @Barun The point of flexbox is to be *flexible*. I can't just make things not-flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized how I could do it from making the example image. Rotate!

http://codepen.io/bjb/pen/ohKnF

If you apply `transform: rotate(180deg)` to both the flex-container and the *things*, you can get its contents to display right while getting the layout upside down. The markup does need to be changed so the *things* are put in the markup backwards (otherwise the first *thing* would be on the bottom because of the transform).

Comment: When the window gets bigger or smaller, the things per row changes. So that would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't rely too much on automatic calculation done by the browser.**

Look at the method I have created: http://jsfiddle.net/AZtY8/

Considering you have not given `margin`, `padding` and `border`, for:

- 2 items in a row, the flex-basis is given from 50% - 34%
- 3 items, the flex-basis is given from 33% - 26%
- 4 items, the flex-basis is given from 25% - 21%, and so on

### HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="wide"></div>
<div class="wide"></div>
<div class="wide"></div>

<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
body > div {
    background-color: #90a; margin: 4px; padding: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
body > div > div {
    background-color: #af3; margin: 4px;
    height: 100px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 20%;
}
body > div > div.wide {
    flex-basis: 30%;
}
```